# Auto suspend after X minutes to stop myself procrastinating

Tags: linux, cron, productivity

Right now, I'm using a line in `/etc/crontab` to run `pm-suspend` every 30 minutes, but I would like an application displaying a warning before suspending (for example a countdown in the taskbar). An option to snooze it once for 2 minutes would be great too. Disabling it should take some small effort, at least having to log in as root (it does seem to be keeping me away from the `/etc/hosts` file where I block time-wasting sites).

It seems like something that should already exist, yet I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I found this [script](http://www.timteatro.net/2011/01/16/sleep-timer-suspend-script-for-linux/) for a suspend timer with warnings. If you would run this as a cronjob, all you would have to do for snoozing is creating a launcher (or whatever you wm calls it, a link on the desktop, taskbar, wherever you want it) that restarts the current job (with 30 min timer) and execute the script once with a two minute timer.

Comment: Well, this is more of a hint about how to do it myself rather then a solution, but I guess the bounty goes to you. Thanks.

Comment: @M.K. well, thank you. I hope this really helps you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

-----------You can use:-----------

```
shutdown -h [minutes]
```

To shutdown the computer after [minutes].
For example:

```
shutdown -h 10
```

This command will shutdown your computer after 10 minutes.

-----------Or you can use:-----------

```
shutdown -r [minutes]
```

To shutdown the computer after [minutes].
For example:

```
shutdown -r 10
```

This command will reboot your computer after 10 minutes.

-----------And you also can use:-----------

```
shutdown 2:00
```

Shutdown the computer at 2-oclock

Comment: I want suspend, not shutdown. And yes, I know I can just use 'sleep X; echo "warning"; sleep 120; pm-suspend', but I want something that will show me a warning in the taskbar (or any other visual way), not on the command line that I don't use when wasting my time on the internet.